# CakePHP 2.x - Access php://input directly to deal with large request body

Tags: php, cakephp, upload

I am working on an application that includes a small REST API. One of these methods needs to accept a large (nearly 300MB) binary file upload on a PUT request.

Because the file is quite large, and because there's some risk of several such requests running at once, I'd like to avoid holding the entire request body in memory. I had hoped to do this by reading from the `php://input` stream directly and siphoning it off to a file.

However, the controller's `input()` method appears to be interfering. I understand the rationale for `input()`—once you read the `php://input` stream, it's gone, so `input()` holds onto it for repeated access. Obviously, this is the behavior I wish to bypass in this instance.

It seems, though, that `input()` is being called somewhere before my controller code runs, because by the time I get to `php://input`, there's nothing left to read.

So, my question: Is there a way for a CakePHP controller to stream a very large request body onto disk without first loading the entire thing into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, so I hope the following will save someone else some time.

This turned out to be an error on my part, but not one related to CakePHP. If you read `php://input` from your controller without having called `Controller::input()`, you will (normally) get the raw request body as you'd expect.

My problem was that I had inadvertently set the request header `Content-Type: application/json`. This caused CakePHP's REST code to try to parse the body as input. When I correctly set the type (in my case `application/x-gzip`) everything functioned correctly.